# javascript drag and drop - prevent elements from dropping into another droppable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title says it - if i drop the fisrt element in a "well", the second droppable element can be dropped inside the first element. Also i need to prevent several elements from dropping into the same "well".
HTML goes like this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Word 3</td>
                    <td><div class="well" style="max-width: 200px;" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="btn btn-primary" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Move 1</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Word 2</td>
                    <td><div class="well" style="max-width: 200px;" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="btn btn-primary" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Move 2</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Word 1</td>
                    <td><div class="well" style="max-width: 200px;" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
                    <td><div class="btn btn-primary" id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">Move 3</div></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS goes like this :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery UI for this as the implementation is extremely easy.

To define a droppable:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
    accept: ".special" // .selector will only allow elements to be dropped on it that the class .special
});
```

To update that:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "accept", ".special2" );
```

To make an element draggable:

```
// Allow elements with class .selector to be dragged
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "enable" );
```

To update that:

```
// Disable dragging for elements with class .selector
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "disable" );
```

---

In your case you could enable all three element as such:

```
$( "#drag1, #drag2, #drag3" ).draggable( "enable" );
// Make #drag1 one droppable, accepts #drag2
$( "#drag1" ).droppable({
    accept: "#drag2"
});
// So so on so forth...
```

---

These few lines can be reproduced with whichever classes and elements you are wanting to effect. It is much easier than the JavaScript version with all of the attributes and functions.

**Make sure to include:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Docs:

[Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)

[Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-enable)

[Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_draggable.htm)

Comment if you have any questions

Answer (score 3):

Problem is when you're dropping your element anywhere over one of the wells or its content (!) the `drop()` function will be called. The `ev.target` inside that function however will point to the  actual element you are dropping on which might not be the well but another element you dropped earlier.

So you need to check inside `drop()` whether `ev.target` is as valid drop target.

A very simple test:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (ev.target.id.match("drag"))
      return;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    stop();
}
```

---

### Additional information

This is due to so called event bubbling.

When an event like `drop` occurs its send to the target. The target can then decide catch it when there is a listener registered for that event, e. g. via the `ondrop` attribute. If there is no listener to catch the event it is send to the elements parent.

That parent now decides whether to catch the event or send it to its own parent and so on...

`ev.target` however will still point to the element the event initially was send to.

Comment: If you happen to use class instead of id, to match use this line
$(ev.target).attr('class').match('your-class')